# Open MS Access file in Linux

Tags: database, linux, qt, odbc

I'm trying to open MS Access database file with QT in Linux.

So, I have installed Easysoft MS Access ODBC Driver with unixODBC. There is my odbc.ini file:

```
[Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS]
Description = MS Acess db driver
Driver = /usr/local/easysoft/access/lib/libesmdb.so
Setup = /usr/local/easysoft/access/lib/libesmdbS.so
```

and there is odbcinst.ini file:

```
[ACCESS_SAMPLE]
Driver = Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS
mdbfile = /home/user/personal_base.mdb
```

Also, I have installed odbc plugin for qt:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-odbc
```

Now how can I open mdb-file with Qt in **Linux**?

In MS Windows I do it such way:

```
bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=C:/personal_base.mdb");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"), db.lastError().text());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I try to change db.setDataBaseName to

```
...
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS};DSN='ACCESS_SAMPLE'");
...
```

But it returns an error:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified QODBC3: Unale to connect
```

What's the matter?

Comment: It seems that Microsoft Access might not be the best solution for a cross-platform database. You should look into SQLite if you want to distribute your database with your application. Otherwise, go with a server like MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But, sorry to say, I can't use any another solution in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I use for building the proper DSN for connecting to SQL Server from Mac, Linux, and Windows.  I believe that your connection string isn't correct in your code. Perhaps it will help get you started.

```
QString SQLServerProvider::buildDSN(QString server, QString database, QString username, QString password)
{
#ifdef Q_WS_MACX
    QString dsn = QString("DRIVER=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so;SERVER=%1;TDS_VERSION=8pClient;DATABASE=%2;PORT=1433;UID=%3;PWD=%4;").arg(server).arg(database).arg(username).arg(password);
#endif

#ifdef Q_WS_X11
    QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=%1;TDS_VERSION=8.0;PORT=1433;DATABASE=%2;UID=%3;PWD=%4;").arg(server).arg(database).arg(username).arg(password);
#endif

#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;UID=%3;PWD=%4;").arg(server).arg(database).arg(username).arg(password);
#endif
    return dsn;
}
```

I know that you are trying to connect to a Microsoft Access database, but perhaps if you replace FreeTDS and a few other paraneters in the Q_WS_X11 part, that will work for you. I have not used Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS before so I'm not 100% sure of how DSNs should be formatted for this driver. Have a read [here](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html) if you haven't already as it explains how to test ODBC DSN connections using isql. If you need further assistance, let me know and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But finaly I decided to re-build  Qt SDK with `-qt-sql-odbc` configure key

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your DSN-Less connection to look :-

```
Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/access/lib/libesmdb.so;mdbfile=/home/user/personal_base.mdb
```

Add your your machines library path :-

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/easysoft/lib:/usr/local/easysoft/access/lib:/usr/local/easysoft/unixODBC/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Finally email support@easysoft.com and ask them for the latest version of the driver.